# document.cookie returning undefined for XMDocument in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

On a HTML page in Firefox, running the simple JS through Scratchpad:

```
alert(document.cookie)
```

Will pop-up an alert with the data in the cookie.

I have a response from another PHP script that returns XML:

```
<response>
    <success>1</success>
    <errorMessage></errorMessage>
    <updateElements><login_header>Hello UserA</login_header></updateElements>
    <return></return>
    <redirect></redirect>

</response>
```

However, using Scratchpad on this page results in "undefined" being popped up.

The command:

```
alert(document)
```

Pops up:

```
[object XMLDocument]
```

There is certainly a cookie being passed and returned in the request and response headers, and Firefox "View Page Info" is showing the cookie as set.

I had tried:

```
dir(document)
```

in Firefox but just got back one result. In Chrome however, I get the full list back. For cookie, it says:

```
[Exception: DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': Access is denied for this document.]
```

In addition, I have checked and HttpOnly is NOT set for this cookie:

```
Set-Cookie: test_installer=123447; path=/; domain=www.test.com
Set-Cookie: test_login=48445501; path=/; domain=www.test.com
```

Testing this in IE 11, if I turn disable "XSS Filter", it runs fine and shows me the cookie.

I am guessing this must be some kind of XSS protection in Firefox and Chrome.

How do I access the cookie data in JS?

Comment: It seems to me that cookie data is tied by the browser to a particular end point. For security reasons, code on one page can't access cookies on other pages. The solution would be to expose the necessary data as part of the XML response.

Comment: They are both in the same domain and path however. I would have thought that would have been enough. Is this some kind of protection in modern browsers I am not aware of? I am looking at performing CSS so can't modify the code.